# display a specific module -- dotnetnuke

Tags: dotnetnuke-module

I am building a site 
I have three modules displayed on my page. I have 3 links on the left pane of my page I have three links.

I want to point each one of these links to each of those modules. When a link is clicked I want to display only that specific module and hide others.

http://localhost/dotnetnuke_community/Directory/tabid/107/Default.aspx
When I use the above link, it displays the whole page with all the 3 modules. I tried to display the module in specific using ModuleId, but that hasn't worked for me.

Can someone help me with it? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How are your modules packaged?

You can search for your Modules via the ModuleController.GetModuleBy.... and then Response.Redirect(NavigateUrl(... to get to the Module on a particular Tab.